# Can't Disable Chinese apps on Samsung Note 3

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-3

A relative picked picked up a 'Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N9006' on his trip to China.

It was misbehaving so I did a reset. When it booted I noticed a few Chinese icons on the Home screen. Opening them takes me to a bunch of Chinese porn sites!

I removed the icons and an app called ChatOn but now I have 4 new Chinese apps that have been downloaded and started automatically!

When I Stop and Disable them they come back.

So what do I do? I don't trust the device as it is. What are my choices?

Root it and try to clean it that way? I don't even know how they are being downloaded. Can I trust the factory ROM at all?

Install a different ROM on it?

Thanks.

---

```
Device Info:
Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N9006
Android 4.4.2
Baseband: MT6582
Build: JSS15J.N9006ZCUBMI5
```

Comment: You can try to root this by following a thread on [XDA Forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2495375)

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the factory ROM has the preloadinstaller.apk, and will reinstall any app that isnt installed, forget if it is every reboot or only on the first one. But I would root, install a file browser that supports root, Search for preloadinstaller.apk then rename/delete it. Then remove the apps. That should stop the apps from reinstalling once they are deleted. Hope this helps ya.

Comment: Thx. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Vic No problem, let us know if it works out for ya. Also as far as if you should trust the default rom, It depends on who built the rom. I have read many stories about people buying what they thought were legit phones from China, only to find out that they are knock-offs and are loaded with spam apps. I find it hard to believe that even in China that porn apps would be installed by default. Lol. Hope this isnt the case for ya, as far as a knock off phone.

Comment: Yes I read about the fact that there are clones. I posted another question for that [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/114501/115642)