# How to find out if note 10 lite is fake?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-10.1

If I'm going to buy used note 10 lite, what's the way to check is original and not fake?

Comment: boot into download mode and find the model number

Comment: Thank you. Is there an official site where I can put this model number or serial number and find out if it's original?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Samsung Galaxy Note 3 SM-N9006: Chinese knockoff/clone or genuine phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114501/samsung-galaxy-note-3-sm-n9006-chinese-knockoff-clone-or-genuine-phone)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Galaxy S7 - How can i check which CPU chipset do i have?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/150397/galaxy-s7-how-can-i-check-which-cpu-chipset-do-i-have)

Comment: afaik the download mode screen can't be faked, if you see model number on this screen you can trust it is real model number. search for this model on gsmarena.com. on the other hand, if this device has fastboot mode then it is clearly Mediatek chipset (Samsung don't have fastboot mode) enter download/fastboot mode with *Vol-Down (+ Home) + Power*